# Windows Phone 7 development on Windows 8 using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

Is it possible to develop apps for Windows Phone 7 on Windows 8 or 8.1 using Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: No, it isn't, at least there's no official way to do that. I use both VS2013 and VS2012 instead.

Comment: That is correct, use Visual Studio 2012 to target WP7. You can have multiple versions of Visual Studio installed at the same time. VS2012 Express has a separate version for phone. VS2013 lets you create phone apps (WP8 / WP8.1) with the version for Windows apps.